Radiation Hardening 2: The Randomiser
Inspired by a very recent post here, can you write a program/function that prints (defined by outputting or returning "Hello, World!" (with caps and exclamation) in any manner), before and after "radiation" randomly flips one bit in your program? Use this script to emulate it:
import os

def invert(input_file: str, output_extension: str):
    if not os.path.exists(input_file):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"The file {input_file} does not exist.")
    with open(input_file, "rb") as f:
        data = bytearray(f.read())
    num_bytes = len(data)
    total_bits = num_bytes * 8 
    output_files = []
    for bit_index in range(total_bits):
        byte_index = bit_index // 8
        bit_position = bit_index % 8y
        modified_data = data[:]
        modified_data[byte_index] ^= (1 << bit_position)
        output_file = f"Program_{bit_index + 1}{output_extension}"
        output_files.append(output_file)
        with open(output_file, "wb") as f:
            f.write(modified_data)

    print(f"Generated {len(output_files)} files:")
    for filename in output_files:
        print(f"  {filename}")

input_path = "input.bin"    
output_ext = ".bin"

try:
    invert(input_path, output_ext)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

Scoring is determined by the fewest number of bitflips (number out of the total number of possible single bitflips that fail) that result in a failure wins, with ties broken by fewest bytes. (Thank you Emanresu-A for managing to put that into words)
Good luck!

First post here, hope you enjoy!

Welcome to CGCC! Nice first challenge. No idea how one would accomplish this, but I've thought the same about some other challenges before and I'm almost always proved wrong. ;) +1 from me. Semi-related: also a radiation-hardening hello-world challenge, but with a random byte removed instead of random bit inverted.

@KevinCruijssen: generally, [tag:radiation-hardening] challenges are about how much of your program is fault-tolerant, rather than making an entirely safe program (though if you can achieve that that's better obviously)

It's still not clear what the scoring system is. I'd recommend explicitly saying something along the lines of "fewest number of bitflips that result in a failure wins, with ties broken by fewest bytes" (or whatever you choose it to be) rather than stating two different criteria and not explaining how they work together.

Should probably make an automatic garbling script...

AutoGarbler done... Be warned, makes a large number of files with a large number of bytes.

fewest number of bitflips that result in a failure wins - well, there's obviously a valid program that will be invalidated by 1 bitflip (print('Hello, World!') in python), and also an empty program that needs 0 bitflps (it already doesn't work). Should that read "largest" insted?

'"radiation" randomly flips one bit' vs. 'number of bitflips that result in a failure' — please do not announce changes like that when one or more answers have already been posted.

@doubleunary By that I mean the number out of the total number of possible single bitflips that fail, same meaning, just misphrased

Understood — perhaps you could clarify that in the question?

Yes, sorry mb!!!

Google Sheets, 67 bytes
=let(x,"Hello, World!",y,"Hello, World!",if(x=y,x,"Hello, World!"))

The formula can take a hit in any of the three Hello Worlds except the space therein. The only way to bitflip that string so that it throws an error would be to change one of the characters to " (001000102). That cannot happen with letters because they have a 1 in the second left position, and the string doesn't contain a b (011000102). The space (001000002) can be bitflipped to a quote though.
The formula can also take many kinds of hits in the latter instance of x, and certain kinds of hits elsewhere. For example, the latter = (001111012) can be bitflipped to < (001111002) while keeping the formula functional. I'm ignoring those "safe" hits for the time being, as well as the space bitflip.
Hits in these substrings will thus be assumed to be fatal:



substring
bytes
%




=let(x,"
8
11.94%


",y,"
5
7.46%


",if(x=y,x,"
12
17.91%


"))
3
4.48%


approximate total essential bytes
28
41.79%




You should be able to remove the two closing parentheses for -2 bytes and -1.79% essential bytes.

The formula editor will add those parentheses, as well as the closing quote, when missing. The consensus is that editor-added bytes should be included in the count. See Omitting trailing closing parentheses and How to count bytes FAQ.

I always thought that was normal. Oh well...

Stuck, 0 bytes
In Stuck, an empty program prints Hello, World!.
Radiation will have no effect on this program because it has no bits.
I got the idea for this from "Hello, World!"
